# Opposite prefix to 'de'

Tags: antonyms, negation, prefixes, un-de

Given a word, say *deregulate*, is there a prefix to denote the opposite, rather than simply saying *regulate*? It seems fairly illogical to have one but I was wondering if something existed.

Comment: Erm... in general, the opposite of a word prefixed by *de-* is simply the word - without the prefix. There is nothing illogical about the fact that English doesn't have a specific prefix to mean "not negated". If we had such a prefix, we'd presumably need to put it in front of practically every word we ever used!

Comment: @FumbleFingers If you re-read my question (pun intended) I'm saying that it IS illogical to have one, however "I was wondering if something existed."

Comment: Well, the need for any such "double negation" would be rare indeed, but maybe **un-** fits the bill. My dictionary lists, for example, **undefaced**.

Comment: Another *de* also fits the bil: *de-deregulate*. :)

Comment: These word game questions don't work for me. There is no "opposite" of de. De means to remove from or take out of or to deduct from. How can that have an "opposite"??

Comment: I came to this question wondering what the opposite of devaluate would be. "Overvaluate" implies valuating more than it should be instead of simply increasing the valuation.

Comment: English has various emphatic prefixes including de- and in-, as well as super- and hyper-. Is this what you mean?

Comment: The assumption that the term “opposite” has a clear meaning in the context of the preposition “re” is invalid. You need to state exactly what a word resulting from adding this to “regulate” and other words would mean. If you cannot do that — and I doubt whether you will be able to — you cannot expect anyone to provide a satisfactory answer.

Answer (score 16):

Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary (2003) lists several words in which the prefix *un-* negates a word that *de-* has previously negated:

- undeciphered
- undecomposed
- undefoliated
- undeformed

Such instances are quite rare, however, in comparison to the number of words that use *re-* to override a *de-* negation. Thus, for example, if a doctor decontaminates a wound with antiseptic, but bacteria later reappear, we say that the new germs "recontaminate" the wound, not that they "undecontaminate" it.  Among the word pairs that follow this model are:

- decertify/recertify
- declassify/reclassify
- decolonize/recolonize
- decommission/recommission
- deconsecrate/reconsecrate
- deconstruct/reconstruct
- deemphasize/reemphasize
- deenergize/reenergize
- deescalate/reescalate
- dehydrate/rehydrate
- deinstitutionalize/reinstitutionalize
- delegitimize/relegitimize
- delist/relist
- demilitarize/remilitarize
- denationalize/renationalize
- depolarize/repolarize
- depopulate/repopulate
- deregulate/reregulate
- desegregate/resegregate
- deselect/reselect
- desensitize/resensitize
- destabilize/restabilize
- detach/reattach

Not all of these pairs are exact opposites (and certainly not in all senses of each term), but a number of them are very nearly so.

Still, noting the existence of this group of paired opposites is very far from saying that replacing a *de-* prefix with a *re-* prefix negates the word that *de-* was attached to.  I suspect that Teresa, who contributed an earlier answer nominating *en-* as a possible negating prefix for words containing the *de-* prefix, had a similar (albeit smaller) set of opposed word pairs in mind:

- decamp/encamp
- decipher/encipher
- decode/encode
- decrypt/encrypt
- dethrone/enthrone

Unfortunately, the two instances that Teresa put forward to show *en-* in direct opposition to *de-* weren't good examples; but her argument about *en-* does have some validity, as the five word pairs above demonstrate.

Ultimately, the simple answer to the general question raised in the original post is that no prefix consistently and reliably undoes the negation that *de-* (or *un-* or *dis-*, for that matter) introduces.

Comment: Indeed. And as a general principle, derivational morphology like this is irregular at best and almost totally unpredictable in general. So nobody should expect any more regularity than what's shown here. In fact, this is much more regular than usual, possibly due to the fact the _de-_  and _re-_ are scraps from Latin with some meat left on them.

Comment: As most of Mr. Yargs' answers, this one provides a very detailed discussion of the general matters that are in the background of the OP's concerns. It, however, does not very explicitly address the specific problem of *?-regulate*. So far as I understand, it may be taken to imply that *reregulate* is the best option, and that the only reason for somebody's hesitating to use it is that it involves two *re* syllables next to each other. Is that the answer, then? (Incidentally, *unde-* to my ear usually suggest that the *de-* action has not yet taken place, rather than that it has been undone.)

Answer (score 9):

**Regulate** means to control or direct according to rule, principle, or law.

**Deregulate** means to remove regulations.

**Re-regulate** could mean to add regulations again, possibly after they've had been removed.

If you're doing something for the first time, simply using the root word is sufficient. If you're doing something a second time, you could use a *re-* prefix, but check for each word.

Comment: Dere-regulate could mean to remove the re-regulations again, when does it just go back to regulate? Warren G might know?

Answer (score 0):

Simply removing the 'de' would work, or using PRO-?
deregulate -> regulate -> proregulate;
degenerative -> generative -progenerative;
On the other hand, since those de-words were not all created strictly logically it seems impossible to come up with a perfect solution to satisfy the original goal here.

Answer (score -1):

I'd like to propose that ‘Do’ would be the correct prefix in my opinion.

If you look at the word devour, the definition is to eat up, or oddly enough, to DE-stroy. Or even DE-finition.. makes me want to research those words more as well. Especially DE-finition or I could write it like deafenision or the loss of one’s ability to perceive correctly. That’s a whole essay for later though lol. Back to the point of the topic, based on the other researchers responses there appears to be no official antonym to the Latin prefix dé, however, after reading the definition of dé I googled the Latin prefix that would mean to add something and the word ‘do’ came up.

Nothing much in English that I’ve found yet uses ‘do’as a prefix. In my opinion that seems intentional. Nonetheless, the opposite of taking away is obviously to give or add to. Which when you look up the definition for the word ‘do’ you will see it clearly includes that.

If you look at the word devour with me, the Latin version was spelled, devorer, de+vorer. Then look at the definition for the Latin word vorer. It means: to eat. Especially the Greek version. So I’d like to publicly propose a new word to the English language for the people. Dovour. Take it or leave it.

Comment: "Nothing much in English that I’ve found yet uses ‘do’as a prefix. In my opinion that seems intentional."  Intentional...how?  I do hope you take a moment to [tour] the site and see the EL&U [help], and welcome.

Comment: I'm afraid that this is not the site on which to propose neologisms, at least without a very good case being made.